# How to extract label text from Push button using Apache PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Lets say I managed to cast a **PDTerminalField** as an instance of  **PDPushButton**.
But looking at the APIs provided I cant guess how to extract the label of said button.

Not adding code due to the verbosity of the application.
This is a sample [pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iUc9AbDkjBEPhITxKdwQjyNTQbs4Dd7j).

Comment: The cause why there is no such `PDPushButton` attribute is that there is no label attribute in the PDF either. A button in a PDF has an appearance stream which can contain any number of graphics and text drawing instructions, so applying text extraction to that appearance stream might be an option.

Comment: @mkl any way i can get a hold of the appearance stream and extract the label from it ?

Comment: @mkl There is a label in /MK/CA (normal caption in the appearance characteristics dictionary)

Comment: So it would be `field.getWidgets().get(0).getAppearanceCharacteristics().getNormalCaption()`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr You are right. But both the **MK** and the **CA** inside it are optional. Thus, one should consider looking up `.getAppearanceCharacteristics().getNormalCaption()` and then try text extraction if the lookup failed.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I added the characteristics entry to my answer. Thanx.

Comment: @mkl 
a follow up question or clarification ; is this by design as certain buttons can change appreance and captions on clicking or mouse down?

Comment: I don't know how much that is by design or by accident. It is true, though, that the buttons can have different appearances, *normal*, *rollover*, and *down*, and they may be completely different indeed, and they also may be completely non-textual. So a single text cannot always coincide with the button appearance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Thanks to @Tilman for correcting me here.)* There indeed is such an attribute, you can access it via `getAppearanceCharacteristics().getNormalCaption()`, but this attribute is optional and its contents are not guaranteed to coincide with the visual appearance of the button because the appearance stream may contain different information. Thus a combined strategy of querying the attribute and reading the appearance stream might be called for.

The appearance stream of a button in a PDF can contain any number of graphics and text drawing instructions to paint the button but this stream is not necessarily easy to read or parse. E.g. in case of the sample file provided by the OP, this stream looks like this:

```
1 0.75 0.666656 rg
0 0 72 20 re
f
q
1 1 70 18 re
W
n
0 g
BT
/HeBo 12 Tf
0 g
6.696 5.857 Td
(My ) Tj
19.992 0 Td
(Button) Tj
ET
Q
```

Here one can already see the button text, "My Button", but obviously one has to do some parsing to retrieve it (in particular as the text encoding need not be derived from ASCII as it is in this case), one has to apply text extraction to the stream.

Unfortunately the main text extraction work horse in PDFBox, the `PdfTextStripper` class, is very hard to apply to anything else than page content. Thus, I use a base class the text stripper is derived from, add only minimal text arrangement capabilities, and apply it to the button appearance stream.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.DrawObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.state.Concatenate;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.state.Restore;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.state.Save;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.state.SetGraphicsStateParameters;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.state.SetMatrix;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.BeginText;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.EndText;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.MoveText;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.MoveTextSetLeading;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.NextLine;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.SetCharSpacing;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.SetFontAndSize;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.SetTextHorizontalScaling;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.SetTextLeading;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.SetTextRenderingMode;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.SetTextRise;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.SetWordSpacing;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.ShowText;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.ShowTextAdjusted;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.ShowTextLine;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.ShowTextLineAndSpace;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.form.PDFormXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.Matrix;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.Vector;

public class SimpleXObjectTextStripper extends PDFStreamEngine {
    public SimpleXObjectTextStripper() {
        addOperator(new BeginText());
        addOperator(new Concatenate());
        addOperator(new DrawObject()); // special text version
        addOperator(new EndText());
        addOperator(new SetGraphicsStateParameters());
        addOperator(new Save());
        addOperator(new Restore());
        addOperator(new NextLine());
        addOperator(new SetCharSpacing());
        addOperator(new MoveText());
        addOperator(new MoveTextSetLeading());
        addOperator(new SetFontAndSize());
        addOperator(new ShowText());
        addOperator(new ShowTextAdjusted());
        addOperator(new SetTextLeading());
        addOperator(new SetMatrix());
        addOperator(new SetTextRenderingMode());
        addOperator(new SetTextRise());
        addOperator(new SetWordSpacing());
        addOperator(new SetTextHorizontalScaling());
        addOperator(new ShowTextLine());
        addOperator(new ShowTextLineAndSpace());
    }

    public String getText(PDFormXObject form) throws IOException {
        stringBuilder.setLength(0);

        processChildStream(form, new PDPage()); 

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void showGlyph(Matrix textRenderingMatrix, PDFont font, int code, String unicode, Vector displacement)
            throws IOException {
        stringBuilder.append(unicode);
    }

    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
}
```

*([SimpleXObjectTextStripper](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/SimpleXObjectTextStripper.java#L54))*

(I included the `import` statements as PDFBox contains several classes of similar names here.)

Using this simple custom stripper class, one can extract text content from field appearances like this:

```
public void showNormalFieldAppearanceTexts(PDDocument document) throws IOException {
    PDAcroForm acroForm = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

    if (acroForm != null) {
        SimpleXObjectTextStripper stripper = new SimpleXObjectTextStripper();

        for (PDField field : acroForm.getFieldTree()) {
            if (field instanceof PDTerminalField) {
                PDTerminalField terminalField = (PDTerminalField) field;
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("* " + terminalField.getFullyQualifiedName());
                for (PDAnnotationWidget widget : terminalField.getWidgets()) {
                    PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = widget.getAppearance();
                    if (appearance != null) {
                        PDAppearanceEntry normal = appearance.getNormalAppearance();
                        if (normal != null) {
                            Map<COSName, PDAppearanceStream> streams = normal.isSubDictionary() ? normal.getSubDictionary() :
                                Collections.singletonMap(COSName.DEFAULT, normal.getAppearanceStream());
                            for (Map.Entry<COSName, PDAppearanceStream> entry : streams.entrySet()) {
                                String text = stripper.getText(entry.getValue());
                                System.out.printf("  * %s: %s\n", entry.getKey().getName(), text);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*([ExtractAppearanceText](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/ExtractAppearanceText.java#L90) helper method)*